# Typescript array of objects returns empty

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework

I need to store array of objects and then convert that into string using JSON.stringify and transfer that string to external link. Below is my typescript code..

```
let order_data = {};

this.storage.get("cart").then((cart) => {
    cart.forEach((element, index) => {
        orderItems.push({ "product_id": element.product.id, "quantity": element.qty });
    });
});

console.log(orderItems);

order_data =  {
    "customer_name": "Singh",
    "line_items": orderItems,
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(order_data));
```

In my console I got empty array of objects.....

{"customer_name":"Singh","line_items":[]}

Anyone here pls help me out of this... Thank you in advance....

Comment: You'll need to read up on promises: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using ES6 promise here. Promise works asynchronously. By the time your promise gets resolved, code below the promise is already got executed. You need to write that code inside `.then()` block:

```
let order_data = {};

this.storage.get("cart").then((cart) => {
    cart.forEach((element, index) => {
       orderItems.push({ "product_id": element.product.id, "quantity": element.qty });
    });

    console.log(orderItems);

    order_data =  {
      "customer_name": "Singh",
      "line_items": orderItems,
    }

    console.log(JSON.stringify(order_data));
});
```

Comment: I'm new here. I got orderItems array value outside the promise and displayed in console and not been reflected in order_data.. I declared orderItems as orderItems: any[] = [];

Comment: Thanks dude, now the code works fine. I should use the code inside the promise. Thanks once again

Answer (score 0):

Promises do not execute synchronously with the surrounding code. When you call `this.storage.get("cart")`, it kicks off an asynchronous block of code that runs parallel to the rest of your code. So the `.then` does not get called immediately. Instead, it immediately goes to execute the next line after the promise, `console.log`.

Once the `.get` call successfully finishes executing, then your `.then` will run. So you will need to put your console logs inside of that `.then` call to guarantee they will contain the results of your `.get` call.

```
let order_data = {};

this.storage.get("cart").then((cart) => {
    cart.forEach((element, index) => {
        orderItems.push({ "product_id": element.product.id, "quantity": element.qty });
    });

    console.log(orderItems);

    order_data = {
        "customer_name": "Singh",
        "line_items": orderItems,
    }

    console.log(JSON.stringify(order_data));
});
```

Alternatively, if you absolutely must have this run synchronously, you can utilize javascript's `async/await` functionality. Though I would recommend against it as it would cause your UI thread to lag and act choppy.